# is there a way to set the window title on the right?

Tags: qt, qml

Recently I am working on the layout right to left (RTL) localization support for my app, but it seems  **LayoutMirroring.enabled: true** doesn't work for the window title.here is my demo code as following:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    id:root
    flags: Qt.Window

    LayoutMirroring.enabled: true
    LayoutMirroring.childrenInherit: true
    Row {
        //        LayoutMirroring.enabled: true
        //       LayoutMirroring.childrenInherit: true
        spacing: 20
        LayoutMirroring.enabled: true
        Repeater {
            model: 5
            Rectangle {
                color: "red"
                opacity: (5 - index) / 5
                width: 70; height: 30
                Text {
                    text: index + 1+" hello"
                    width:parent.width
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Test{
        id:t4

    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        t4.sohalDigVisible = true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `LayoutMirroring` affects `Window.contentItem` not the `Window` itself. Anyway I guess QML/Qt cannot access window title since it is the responsibility of OS.

Comment: The title is windows part. On a windows that is configured for RTL, the title will be on the right side

Comment: Have you seen this? https://forum.qt.io/topic/3049/solved-qt-layout-direction-and-window-title-bar/9

Comment: Also, it is my understanding that if you use Quick Controls 2's ApplicationWindow instead of Window, then layout mirroring should also affect the window appearance. It would be great to know if that is true or not.